# How to make text appear conditionally based on form input in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, forms, conditional-statements

Is it possible to create a fillable form in MS Word where text appears conditionally based on what the user inputs in the form?

For instance, if the user selects *Option 1* from a Drop Down List, I want more questions to appear based on this selection.

I'm happy to work with Macros, although my experience with them is limited so alternative options may be preferred if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a **Bookmark** to mark or identify your dropdown list. Assume it is named "MyDropdown."
Then use a **Ref field** inside an **IF field** to test its value.
Something along the lines of:

```
{ IF { Ref MyDropdown } = "Option 1" "truetext" }
```

This can be shortened to:

```
{ IF MyDropdown = "Option 1" "truetext" }
```

where truetext is what you want to appear.

If it is lengthy, you would want to save your truetext as an **AutoText Entry** named uniquely. Here I am assuming Opt1Text as the name.

```
{ IF MyDropdown = "Option 1" "{ AutoText Opt1Text }" }
```

*The field delimiters {} cannot simply be typed.* You have to let Word insert them. One way to do that is with **Ctrl+F9**.

Once a change is made in your dropdown, normally you need to select your target area and **press the F9 key to update the Ref field**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this and it isn't working for me - I'm not sure why. I have bookmarked the dropdown list as "DropDown" and it has the options "Option1" and "Option2". But for some reason when I try { IF DropDown = "Option1" "You have selected Option 1." } nothing appears when Option1 is selected. I've inserted the brackets using Ctrl+F9 as you said, as well, so I really don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: @user1224012  You need to use the F0 key to update the fields. Also, which kind of dropdown are you using? Legacy Formfield or Content Control? If a legacy formfield, the document has to be protected for filling in forms. Try creating a simple cross-reference field to your bookmark and updating that after you change. Does that work? Then the IF field should also work when updated.